# assigning dictionary as value to dictionary key

Tags: python, dictionary

I am beginner to python, can i assign dictionary as value to key of another dictionary

```
 d={'a':NONE}
 d1={'b':1}
```

result should be :

```
d={'a':{'b':1}}
```

Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why not ? the [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) value can be a value or any data structure like `dict` or `list` or ... . Actually the values of a dictionary can be of any type, but the keys must be of an hashable data type such as strings, numbers, or tuples.

```
>>> d={'a':None}
>>> d1={'b':1}
>>> d['a']=d1
>>> d
{'a': {'b': 1}}
```

Answer (score 3):

A value can be **any** Python object.

```
d['a'] = d1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can assign it like this:

`d['a'] = d1`

Printing d returns:

`{'a': {'b': 1}}`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to what others are saying, namely:

```
d['a'] = d1
```

Let me also point out that the assignment that you wrote works:

```
d={'a':{'b':1}}
```

In either case, the results are equal: a `dict` with one key-value pair, the value of which is a `dict`.